# how to make my mainactivity appear only for the first installation in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have some code to run in my main activity as a splashscreen how do I let that appear only for the first opening after installation

Comment: elaborate.... your question

Comment: This shows no intent and research at all.

Answer (score 4):

Use Sharedprefernce and change the Sharedprefernce data after the first time appear. And bypass the activity or splash screen according to you need

Eg :- save Boolean variable as **false** into **Sharedpreference by default**.
As soon as first time your splash screen runs change the Boolean to **true** and make  if else statement according to that Boolean. If Boolean contains true then bypass the splash screen or if Boolean contains false show the splash screen and change the Boolean to **true**

splashscreen.java

into your onCreate method

```
   SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("splash_screen_prefernce", MODE_PRIVATE);
        if(prefs.getBoolean("bypass_boolean", false)){
            Intent intent=new Intent(SplashScreen.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
```

write this line when your splash screen is completed 
and you want to move to next screen or activity

```
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("splash_screen_prefernce", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putBoolean("bypass_boolean", true);
    editor.apply();
```